# How do you determine the view-up vector?

Tags: graphics, linear-algebra

This is an excerpt from **Fundamentals of Computer Graphics** by Peter Shirley. On Page 114 (in the 3rd edition it reads:

> We'd like to be able to change the viewpoint in 3D and look in any
>   direction. There are a multitude of conventions for specifying viewer
>   position and orientation. We will use the following one:
>
> - the eye position e
> - the gaze direction g
> - the view-up vector t
>
> The eye position is a location that the eye "sees from". If you think
>   of graphics as a photographic process, it is the center of the lens.
>   The gaze direction is any vector in the direction that the viewer is
>   looking. **The view-up vector is any vector in the plane that both
>   bisects the viewer's head into right and left halves and points "to
>   the sky" for a person standing on the ground**. These vectors provide us
>   with enough information to set up a coordinate system with origin `e`
>   and `uvw` basis.....

The bold sentence is the one confusing me the most. Unfortunately the book provides only very basic and crude diagrams and doesn't provide any examples.

Does this sentence mean that all view-up vectors are simply `(0, 1, 0)`?

I tried it on some examples but it didn't quite match up with the given solutions (though it came close sometimes).

Answer (score 8):

Short answer:  the view-up vector is not derived from other components: instead, it is a user input, chosen so as to ensure the camera is right-side up.  Or, to put it another way, the view-up vector is *how* you tell your camera system what direction "up" is, for purposes of orienting the camera.

---

The reason you need a view-up vector is that the position and gaze direction of the camera is not enough to completely determine its pose:  you can still spin the camera around the position/gaze axis.  The view-up vector is needed to finish locking down the camera;  and because people usually prefer to look at things right-side up, the view-up vector is conventionally a fixed direction, determined by how the scene is oriented in your coordinate space.

In theory, the view-up vector could be in any direction, but in practice "up" is usually a coordinate direction.  Which coordinate is "up" is a matter of convention:  in your case, it appears the Y-axis is "up", but some systems prefer the Z-axis.

That said, I will reiterate: you *can* choose pretty much any direction you want.  If you want your first-person POV to "lean" (e.g., to look around a corner, or to indicate intoxication), you can tweak your view-up vector to accomplish this.  Also, consider camera control in a game like Super Mario Galaxy...

Answer (score 3):

I took a graphics class last year, and I'm pretty rusty. I referenced some old notes, so here goes.

I think that bolded line is just trying to explain what the view-up vector (`VUP`) would mean in one case for sake of introduction, not what it necessarily is in all cases. The wording is a bit odd; here's a rewording: "Consider a person standing on the ground. `VUP` in that case would be the vector that bisects the viewer's head and points to the sky."

To determine a standard upward vector, do the following:

1. Normalize `g`.
2. `g_norm x (0,1,0)` gives you `view-right`, or the vector to the right of your camera view
3. `view-right x g` gives you `VUP`.

You can then apply a rotation if you wish to do so.

Comment: From what I understood, the view-up vector somehow follows naturally from the two main vectors we set: the camera's location and what it is looking at (the gaze).
The goal is, to use `e`, `g` and `v` to generate a basis for the camera's coordinate system.

Comment: `v`? Is that `VUP`? Or a typo? Your original post says `VUP` is `t`.

Comment: Sorry you're right - it should say `t`. The reason is because `v` is used as one of the bases of the camera space `u, v, w`

Comment: Got it. I wrote something else, and realized that it was completely wrong. Here's the thing: With two directional vectors, you can generate a third vector. `e` doesn't help us here, since the position is independent of the viewing axes. All you have left is `g`, which is not enough to determine `t`. You can determine `t` if you want to lock it to a plane, by using a known axis like `world-down` (or whatever you want to call it`. But to have actual camera freedom, you need to determine `VUP` at least once yourself.

Comment: Following that. The only "natural" part comes from the power of transformation matrices. Once you've determined your initial view, you can simply apply transformations (rotations, translations) to your viewing matrix to move it around programmatically. Although if you ever want to "jump" the camera to a particular location or view, you'll have to specify `VUP`/`t` yourself again.

Comment: I don't think that answers the question though.... how do I pick a `VUP`? I obviously can't just choose random numbers.

Comment: I modified my answer, see if that's what you were originally looking for. You can still determine a `VUP` based on a particular orientation beforehand, by finding it in a local space and then rotating that space to align with `g`.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this sentence mean that all view-up vectors are simply (0, 1, 0)?

No `(0,1,0)` is the world up vector. We're looking for the camera's up vector.

Others have written in depth explanations. I will provide the code below, which is largely self documenting. Example is in DirectX C++.

```
DirectX::XMVECTOR Camera::getDirection() const noexcept
{
    // camDirection = camPosition - camTarget
    const dx::XMVECTOR forwardVector{0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};
    const auto lookVector = dx::XMVector3Transform( forwardVector,
        dx::XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw( m_pitch, m_yaw, 0.0f ) );
    const auto camPosition = dx::XMLoadFloat3( &m_position );
    const auto camTarget = dx::XMVectorAdd( camPosition,
        lookVector );
    return dx::XMVector3Normalize( dx::XMVectorSubtract( camPosition,
        camTarget ) );
}

DirectX::XMVECTOR Camera::getRight() const noexcept
{
    const dx::XMVECTOR upVector{0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    return dx::XMVector3Cross( upVector,
        getDirection() );
}

DirectX::XMVECTOR Camera::getUp() const noexcept
{
    return dx::XMVector3Cross( getDirection(),
        getRight() );
}
```